# mapping integers 1-max onto 100 integers from 1-1,000,000

Tags: java

I need to map a Java integer from the range 1-max to the range 1-1,000,000, but only using 100 particular (non-linear) values in the destination range.  The 100 values are:
1-10 (so the first 10 values map to themselves)
then by 5's: 15, 20, 25 ... to 100
then by 50's: 150, 200, 250 ... to 1,000
and so on, the final values being 900,000  950,000 and 1,000,000
I can't quite get my head around anything more elegant than a bag of nested if/else-if's.
The solution is not time/cycle sensitive.

Comment: show us your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinks this will do it with two loops.

```java
      List<Integer> values =
            new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

      int x = 1;
      while (x < 100_000) {
         for (int k = 15 * x; k <= 100 * x; k += 5 * x) {
            values.add(k);
         }
         x *= 10;
      }

      values.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Build an array of elements, and then look up the result.  You only need to build the array once.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
// note we start at 0 so indexes work as expected.
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) list.add(i);
for(int i=10;i<100;i+=5) list.add(i);
etc...
Integer result = list.get(input);
```